# Blazor - Generate HTML at compile time

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I'm trying to create a custom Razor component that will take an SVG file as parameter and render that file into my page **at compilation time**. My current understanding of Blazor is that the components are rendered during every page load. In my specific use case, I would like this custom component to be rendered at compilation time and be part of the plain HTML markup.

More details about my specific need: Razor component that takes the name of an icon as parameter, looks into a local folder on dev box containing hundreds of SVG icon files, opens the corresponding file and renders the content onto the page as inline SVG, at the build step. This is to avoid having to use an outside tool to generate hundreds of components (one for each icon).

Comment: In OnInitializedAsync build the html, wrap it in a MarkupString, and render that. You can override ShouldRender and return false to tell blazor the content never changes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a code weaver, or even better the new Source Generators to do this https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/

Comment: this is a good suggestion. https://channel9.msdn.com/events/dotnetConf/2020/C-Source-Generators-Write-Code-that-Writes-Code?term=source%20generators&lang-en=true

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, you're going to have to generate this code with a an outside tool somehow. What you're asking is called [scaffolding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaffold_(programming)), and there are many ways to do it, but Blazor on its own is not able to "generate itself".

You can generate the razor files with a tool such as [T4 Text Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2019) or [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/). I personally vouch for T4, it's very well integrated within the MS stack and is very mature. Gulp is quite popular with the JS crowd, but you need to install a bunch of extra stuff to get it to work in VS. And it's Javascript, whereas T4 is C# and already present in VS.